# Facebook invalid keyhash on playstore APK

Tags: android, facebook

I get an Invalid key hash error when I install my app from play store.
When the same APK is installed manually, there is no keyhash error.

I generated 2 keys

one :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Second :

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageInfo(pContext, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
        }
    }
```

Both of them gave different hashes which were added on FB console.

Why the APK from the Play Store gives invalid key hash error?
Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I need to enter the key flashed on device.That's absurd but worked.